# $emit inside async method - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here's my child's component async method:

```
async created () {
  this.$parent.$emit('loader', true)
  await this.fetchData()
  this.$parent.$emit('loader', false)
}
```

`fetchData` does an axios get call, to fetch data from API. However in a vue-devtools (events tab) i can only see the events, after i change the code and it hot reloads. Also i've set up `console.log()` in a parent component:

```
mounted() {
  this.$on('loader', (value) => {
    console.log(value)
  })
}
```

And i can see only `false` in a console. My purpose is to emit loader set to true (so i can show the loader), then set it to false, when data is fetched.

My fetchData method:

```
import http from '@/http'

fetchData() {
  return http.getOffers().then((resp) => {
    this.offersData = resp.data
  })
}
```

Contents of http.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import config from '@/config'

const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.API_URL
})

export default {
  /* calculator */
  getOffers() {
    return HTTP.get('/url')
  }
}
```

If i directly use `return axios.get()` in `async created()`, then it works. Problem is in this imported http instance.

**Final solution**

One of the problems was using different lifecycles, thanks to [Evan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572938/evan-kennedy) for mentioning this.

Another problem was with async / await usage, changes to a `fetchData()` method:

```
import http from '@/http'

async fetchData() {
  await http.getOffers().then((resp) => {
    this.offersData = resp.data
  })
}
```

I had to make this method async and use await on axios request, since await is [thenable](https://scotch.io/tutorials/asynchronous-javascript-using-async-await), it does work. Also i've spotted an issue in https.js:

```
export default {
  /* calculator */
  getOffers() {
    return HTTP.get('/url')
  }
}
```

It returns `HTTP.get()`, not a promise itself, i could have used `then` here, and it would work, but, for flexibility purposes i didn't do that.

But, still, i don't get why it didn't work:

```
fetchData() {
  return http.getOffers().then((resp) => {
    this.offersData = resp.data
  })
}
```

Isn't it already returning a promise, since it's chained with then... So confusing.

Retested again, seems like `return` is working, lol.

Comment: Does `console.log(this)`  from the async method return a Vue Object or a promise?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien, i just did `console.log(this)` instead of `console.log(value)` and got Vue object.

Comment: Be careful by doing `.catch`. **This will suppress ALL errors** you get in the `.then` callback too. It's better do do it in the .then's 2nd parameter: `axios.get('/url').then((resp) => {}, (err) => {})` [infographic](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/15911/promises.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `created` on the child component is getting called before `mounted` on the parent component, so you're beginning to listen after you've already started your Axios call.

The [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) lifecycle event method does not do anything with a returned promise, so your method returns right after you begin the Axios call and the rest of the vue component lifecycle continues.

You should be able to change your parent observation to the `created` event to make this work:

```
created() {
  this.$on('loader', (value) => {
    console.log(value)
  })
}
```

If for some reason you need to do something that can't be accessed in `created`, such as accessing `$el`, I'd suggest moving both to the `mounted` lifecycle hook.

Comment: Clever, I did not spot the mounted in the second one!

Comment: A good notice, now my `console.log(value)` fires `true` and `false` at the same time. Something wrong with `async` now.

Comment: Great, this is what you want, right? Assuming `fetchData` did something in-between the `true` & `false`

Comment: They should be true & false, synchronously, like: set loader to true, then fetch data, when data is fetched, set loader to false. But now it's instantly true and false at the same time,

Comment: What I'd guess is that your `fetchData` method isn't returning a promise. If `fetchData` properly returns a promise, this should wait for that to finish. If possible, can you update your question to include what that method returns? You can also test by replacing `await this.fetchData()` with `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))` which just waits 2 seconds

Comment: I've added my `fetchData()` method, as you can see, there's no issues with it. But if i directly `$emit` in axios promise - it works as intended. But i want to make it work using async / await

Comment: Thank you! I think your issue is you'll want to `return` the promise. So change your statement to: `return axios.get(url)` rather than `axios.get(url)`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you are in fact returning the promise. I'm not sure the issue, but try replacing your fetch data call with the raw `await axios.get(...)` and see if that works.

Comment: What does changing it to `console.log(await this.fetchData())` log?

Comment: returns `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply suggest restructuring your method, as there isn't really a need to make an async method since axios itself is asnychronus.

If you already have the fetchData method defined, and the goal is to toggle the loader state when a call is being made, something like this should do.

```
fetchData () {
    this.$parent.$emit("loader", true)

    axios.get(url)
        .then(resp => {
            this.data = resp
            this.$parent.$emit("loader", false)
        })
}
```

Of course these then statements could be combined into one, but it's the same idea.

Edit: (using the parent emit function)

```
fetchData () {
    this.loader = true

    axios.get(url)
        .then(resp => this.data = resp)
        .then(() => this.loader = false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not my case, because loader itself is in a parent component, otherwise i would have used it in axios promise of course.

Comment: I get it. Wouldn't the same thing work but for calling emit?

Comment: It works in axios promise, but i want to make it work using `async` / `await` :)

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to achieve is to tell the direct parent that it's no longer loading, you would have to emit to the same instance like so

```
async created () {
  this.$emit('loader', true)
  await this.fetchData()
  this.$emit('loader', false)
}
```

By removing the`$parent`, you will emit from the current component.

```
--Root
 --My-page.vue
   -Some-child.vue
```

Now you will emit from `some-child.vue` to `my-page.vue`. I have not tried, but theoretically what you are doing by emiting via parent: (`this.$parent.$emit('loader', false)`) You are emitting from `my-page.vue` to `root`.

So If you have a `$on` or `@loader` on the component like so: `<Some-child @loader="doSomething"/>`, This will never run due to you emitting from the parent.

Comment: Let's say, i have an `$emit` in Some-child, and i'm listening to that `$emit` form My-page using `this.$on`, since `this.$on` works with `$emit` ONLY within the same Vue instance, thats why i've used `this.$parent.$emit`.

Comment: Oh, right. That seems like a workaround, or? I've not used $on myself. However, I tend to add the listeners to the custom-element as seen above. I might be wrong, but In my eyes, doing stuff on $parent seems dirty as in the future, a parent might change.

Comment: Seems like Vue is allowing using `$on` with `$emit` as alternative. IN what cases you are using `$on`? I wish Vue will become strictly opinionated, just like an angular, so there should be just 1 way to make a stuff work.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just went through the docs again to refresh my memory. I cannot personally find a good use case as per now on when I'd want to use `$on`. However, there is one [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Programmatic-Event-Listeners). I believe the "normal" way to emit data is to do it the [`v-on:` / `@` way](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event).